# wp_mail keeps sending the same mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use `wp_mail` to send some data to me but this should only be done **once**.
In order to avoid continuously sending mails, I created an extra [option](https://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API). 
Yet, it still keeps on sending the same mail over and over again when I test it.

My code is as follows:

```
function track_details_admin() {

    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') && ! is_admin ) {   
        return false;   
    } 

    $tracking = get_option('track_details');

        // mail settings                 
        $send_mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        // Send mail only if it wasn't sent before
        if( $tracking === false && $tracking != '1' ) {
            $send_mail; 
        }

        // If email is sent succesfully update option so it won't be sent again
        if( $send_mail ) {

            //If option already exists, update else create new
            if ( $tracking !== false ) {
                update_option( 'track_details', '1' );
            } else {
                add_option( 'track_details', '1' );
            }

        } 

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'track_details_admin', 99 );
```

Inside the options table, I can see that the option `'track_details'` is created and set to `1` after a mail is sent.

Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: `$tracking != '1'` are you sure that you are checking here a string value ?

Comment: `$send_mail = wp_mail(…)` - _this_ already sends the mail. Placing any if statement _after_ that is not going to  magically un-send it again. `if(...) { $send_mail; }` makes no sense, that doesn’t execute anything, you are just “mentioning” a variable name here, such a statement doesn’t _do_ anything.

Comment: Got it. For the time being, I've used `if( get_option('track_details') != '1' ) {add_action( 'admin_init', 'track_details_admin', 99 );}` so the function doesn't load in the first place if mail is already sent (and option exists). Will also remove related `if statement` code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following script which has different approach to detect the mail is sent or no. I am using actuallly variable `$is_sent` which value is `0` but once email send or if-statement will be true the `$is_sent` value will be get update and become `1`

```
function track_details_admin() {

    if( ! current_user_can('administrator') && ! is_admin ) {   
        return false;   
    } 

    $tracking = get_option('track_details');

        // mail settings                 
        $send_mail = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        $is_sent = 0;

        // Send mail only if it wasn't sent before
        if( $tracking === false && $tracking != '1' ) {
            $send_mail; 
            $is_sent = 1;
        }

        // If email is sent succesfully update option so it won't be sent again
        if( $is_sent == 1 ) {

            //If option already exists, update else create new
            if ( $tracking !== false ) {
                update_option( 'track_details', '1' );
            } else {
                add_option( 'track_details', '1' );
            }

        } 

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'track_details_admin', 99 );
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. Mostly likely because of what @misorude said.